# Ag-grid autoSizeColumns with flex in react

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I using ag-grid in my project.

I want to use autoSizeColumn and flex together
but, flex properties do not apply when autoSizeColumn is called.

If anyone can fix this, please help me

thk :)

column `setFlex(1)` next autoSizeColumn method call.

I think need maintain column flex. but loss column flex

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to use `autoSizeColumn` api but need to control of some specific columns width?
If what I understand is correct, you can set specific columns when you call `autoSizeColumn`

```js
const columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name', colId: 'name', flex: 1 },
    { field: 'age', flex: 2 },
    { field: 'address' },
];

...

const autoSizeName = useCallback() => {
    gridRef.current!.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(['name'], false);
}, []);
```

This `autoSizeName` will only resize `name` column